# How to add a custom body class for pages that are not the front page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom body class `.custom-body` in a WordPress site to all pages that are NOT the front page:

To my `functions.php` I added the following filter:

```
if ( !is_front_page() ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) {
        // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
        $classes[] = 'custom-body';
        // return the $classes array
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

In my header I call the body-function:

`<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

The problem is that `custom-body` is added to all pages, i.e. the if statement doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Look right so let's just check to make sure, which URL do you think is front_page?

Comment: Front_page is the static first page (set in the back end) you call when you access the root domain, e.g. http://loclahost/MyTheme/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the CSS-class conditionally instead of the filter solved the problem:

```
function my_class_names($classes) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    if( !is_front_page() ) $classes[] = 'custom-body';
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
```